# How const char* is stored in static lib and shared lib?

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Recently, by accident, i found that, the libz.a and libz.so compiled by myself, containing the version infomation, whose type is const char*(see [text](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/deflate.c) line no. 55), and you can find the string after opening the library. However, i also installed zlib with apt-get, and there is no corresponding word in the shared library. i just wonder what happened. As far as i concern, const char* data is usually stored in .data1, so where is the const char* data in the lib installed by apt-get?

BTW, i compiled several different versions of zlib, and can find the string in all the libraries.